# After a read timeout, it takes time to shut down the connection in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm currently developing an application using Java 11 and Spring Boot. Within this application, I make calls to two external REST APIs using the RestTemplate library. Below, you'll find the configuration for my Apache HttpClient:

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate proxyRestTemplate() {
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(HTTP_PROXY_HOST, HTTP_PROXY_PORT);
    RequestConfig requestConfig =
        RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(false)
            .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(2000)
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(8000)
            .build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(40);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
            .disableAutomaticRetries()
            .setConnectionTimeToLive(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
  }
```

With this configuration, I make calls to two APIs using Spring Integration's `Http.outboundGateway()`

```
  public IntegrationFlow getDecision() {
    return flow -> {
      flow.channel(c -> c.executor(getAsyncExecutor()))
          .handle(
              Http.outboundGateway(myURL, restTemplateConfig.proxyRestTemplate())
                  .mappedRequestHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
                  .extractPayload(true)
                  .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                  .expectedResponseType(String.class));
    };
  }
```

After the read timeout occurs, there is an additional delay of 7-8 seconds before the connection is closed and released back to the connection pool. As a result, my application's total response time increases to 15-16 seconds, even though my read timeout is set to only 8 seconds. Here are the corresponding log entries for reference:

```
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:00:50.646440127Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] http-outgoing-9 >> "{"request":{"Demo request":""}
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:00:58.651312241Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] http-outgoing-9 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:00:58.651390941Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] http-outgoing-9: Close connection
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:01:06.657634687Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] http-outgoing-9: Shutdown connection
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:01:06.657706848Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] Connection discarded
DEBUG 2023-09-03T21:01:06.657729276Z [resource.labels.containerName: my-service] Connection released: [id: 9][route: {tls}->http://ep.threatpulse.net:80->https://api.xyz.com:443][total available: 3; route allocated: 3 of 20; total allocated: 4 of 40]
```

Comment: The socket timeout, in particular, determines how long your application waits for data from the server before timing out. If you're experiencing an 8-second gap, it might be due to the setSocketTimeout(8000) configuration, and you can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I'm fine with the timeout occurring after 8 seconds, but if you examine the timestamps in the logs, you'll notice that it takes an additional 7-8 seconds to close the connection. This delay ends up causing the overall response time of the application to exceed 8 seconds.

Comment: Any chances to have a simple project from you to play with and reproduce? According to your explanation, it looks like you'd like to not have a delay between `Close connection` and `Shutdown connection` events.

Comment: Yes Artem, I'd like to eliminate the additional delay that occurs after a read timeout before shutting down the connection, especially when operating in a high-load, multi-threaded environment.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your request. Could you please clarify how I can send the project to you?

Comment: Via public GitHub repository. Then I'll pull it locally, build and run to see what is going on. Perhaps using debug on those Apache HTTP Client classes... Of course, you can debug it yourself and determine what takes some time in the connection pool between those two events on the connection.